# How to use k8s ServiceAccount to assume correct AWS Role (IRSA)? Running a Spring Boot app on EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I have Spring Boot (2.6.6) app running in a EKS cluster that tries to authenticate AWS by assuming an AWS role. I've followed this [doc](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.3.2/reference/html/index.html#aws-eks-iam-roles-for-service-accounts-configuration) so far.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And in my application helm/k8s setup:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec
  template:
    metadata:
      ...
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: myapp-service-account
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 123456
      initContainers:
      ...
```

ServiceAccount setup:

```
~ % kubectl get serviceaccounts -n dev                                                   
NAME                         SECRETS   AGE
default                      1         2y1d
myapp-service-account        1         7d2h
..

~ % kubectl get serviceaccounts/myapp-service-account   -n dev -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:role/<aws_role_to_assume>
..
```

But my app doesn't seem to assume the correct role:

> 2022-06-21 17:50:25.284  WARN [my-app,,] 1 --- [           main] s.AwsSecretsManagerPropertySourceLocator : Unable to load AWS secret from /secret/my-app_dev. User: arn:aws:sts::<account_id>:assumed-role/<cluster_generated_default_role> is
> not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: /secret/my-app_dev because no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action (Service: AWSSecretsManager; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 1111111-2222-33333-444444; Proxy: null)

In above, I thought adding `serviceAccountName: myapp-service-account` would allow the app to somehow pick up the new ServiceAccount and thus assume a different role. What am I misconfiguring here?

***EDIT***

Environment variables:

```
~ % kubectl exec my-app-pod-1234-abcd -n dev -- env
...
JAVA_OPTS=
AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE=/var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token
AWS_ROLE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::<aws_account_id>:role/<aws_role_to_assume>
...
```

Comment: If you inspect the pod, do you see the web identity token mounted? The ability for pods to attain the role of the host node can and should be prevented: https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/security/docs/iam/#restrict-access-to-the-instance-profile-assigned-to-the-worker-node

Comment: I believe they are setup. See edit section, I ran an environment variable check on the pod.

Comment: It could be an ordering issue and instance metadata is first in  the chain. Implement the block and check

Comment: The role seems been assumed. The error seems when it try to access a resource: `is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: /secret/my-app_dev`.
Check the policy associated to the role.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the role to the default service account in the namespace:

Example for terraform:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/default_service_account

Comment: this is not the way, you should not use the default service account, rather all apps should use their own service accounts

Comment: I agree, but depends on the case. You can tight it up only to one namespace. It fits if there is an app per namespace

Answer (score 0):

Check the IAM role, have you added the trust relationship there so that your role can be assumed from the service account e.g. it should look like

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/id/<ID>"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "oidc.eks.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/id/<ID>:sub": "system:serviceaccount:<NAMESPACE_NAME>:<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```